# Google map api : placing a marker randomly inside a city

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I did some research about a question but didn't find any answer. And now, I'm wondering if this is possible to do.

More details : I would like to to create a function that take a city in input and return a location (lat + long) randomly inside the city. The problem is that I don't know anything about the city boundaries.
I'm working on api v3 javascript

Do you have an idea of how i can do ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the geocoding service as shown in [**this example**](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple) from the [**documentation**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Geocoder)

Comment: I think geocoding also returns some boundaries for large area locations, you could work on that

Comment: Please write your answer here. If your answer is on an external page using a link then if the link is dead the answer will no longer be accessible.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to get the longs and lats for each point in the polygon for the city to do this cleanly.

Can you not just sidestep the problem by finding a random address, maybe scrape a list of local post offices and pick one at random, then geo-locate it's postcode with the Google Maps API?

It depends what you mean by random to some extent.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer.
Taking all the points for all the city in the world for the polygone would be too long, right ?
The thing is that, when you type a city on google maps, the city appear in color, that's why I'm wondering if their is some sort of "city library".

Comment: The highlighted border that you see on maps.google.com comes from the twitter API: https://dev.twitter.com/